# Inferring language attribute while traversing the dom

Tags: javascript, attributes

I'm working on a site where there there are multiple language attributes declared throughout it. I'm trying to extract all of the text from each language, but sometimes the language is inferred from a parent element, so each element itself may not have the attribute. Sometimes, the element which set the language attribute can be many levels above the node.

For example, if the website structure is like so (simplified):

```
<html>
<body lang="en">
  <header lang="ko">
    <span>氏氏氏氏</span>
    <p lang="en">A whole new world</p>
  </header>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
  <p lang="cn">也称乱数假文或者哑元文本</p>
  <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem</p>
  <footer lang="ja">
    <ul>
      <li>金金金金</li>
      <li>金或金或</li>
      <li lang="ko">중중중중중</li>
      <li>数假</li>
    </ul>
  <footer>
</body>
</html>
</body>
```

Getting all of the elements that have the `lang` attribute is not a good solution, because then the nodes without a `lang` tag are no longer included. I've tried creating a solution with this code, but it does not work well if the parent was set many previous elements above. Perhaps there is a different approach I could take? Or maybe there is an adjustment to this solution that would work well?

```
var findTextNodesWithLangAttribute = function(parentNode, selectedLanguage){
    var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(
        parentNode,
        // Only consider nodes that are text nodes (nodeType 3)
        NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,
        // Object containing the function to use for the acceptNode method
        // of the NodeFilter
        { acceptNode: function(node) {
              // Logic to determine whether to accept, reject or skip node
              // In this case, only accept nodes that have content
              // other than whitespace
              if ( ! /^\s*$/.test(node.data) ) {
                    // Test the language attribute
                    if(node.parentElement.hasAttribute("lang")) {
                        var nodeLang = node.parentElement.attributes["lang"].value;
                    } else if(node.parentNode.parentElement.hasAttribute("lang")) {
          var nodeLang = node.parentNode.parentElement.attributes["lang"].value;
        } else if(node.parentElement.parentElement.hasAttribute("lang")) {
          var nodeLang = node.parentElement.parentElement.attributes["lang"].value;
                    }; 
                  if(nodeLang == selectedLanguage) {
                        return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
                    }
              }
          }
        },
        false
    );

    var nodeList = [];

    while(treeWalker.nextNode()) nodeList.push(treeWalker.currentNode);

    return nodeList;
}
```

Comment: did you try out? if it works for you..go ahead and accept the answer. thx.

Comment: Thanks @santon it works very well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to backtrack up the parent path to find the nearest parent with a lang and see if it matches with the requested language. Here is a snippet that has the modifications to your code.

```js
var findTextNodesWithLangAttribute = function(parentNode, selectedLanguage) {
  var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(
    parentNode,
    // Only consider nodes that are text nodes (nodeType 3)
    NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,
    // Object containing the function to use for the acceptNode method
    // of the NodeFilter
    {
      acceptNode: function(node) {
        // Logic to determine whether to accept, reject or skip node
        // In this case, only accept nodes that have content
        // other than whitespace
        if (!/^\s*$/.test(node.data)) {
          // Test the language attribute
          var nearestParentWithLang = node.parentElement;
          if (!nearestParentWithLang.hasAttribute("lang")) {
            nearestParentWithLang = _findNearestParentElementWithLang(node.parentElement);
          }
          if ( nearestParentWithLang.attributes["lang"].value == selectedLanguage) {
            return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
          }
        }
      }
    },
    false
  );

  var nodeList = [];

  while (treeWalker.nextNode()) nodeList.push(treeWalker.currentNode);

  return nodeList;
}

 function _findNearestParentElementWithLang(textParent) {
   if(!textParent) return textParent;
   while(textParent){
      if(textParent.hasAttribute("lang")) return textParent;
        else textParent = textParent.parentElement;
    }
 }


var langNodes = findTextNodesWithLangAttribute(document.body, "ja");

langNodes.forEach(function(val, ind) {
 console.log(val.nodeValue);
});
```

```html
<body lang="en">
  <header lang="ko">
    <span>氏氏氏氏氏</span>
    <p lang="en">A whole new world</p>
  </header>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
  <p lang="cn">也称乱数假文或者哑元文本</p>
  <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem</p>
  <footer lang="ja">
    <ul>
      <li>金金金金</li>
      <li>金金金金</li>
      <li lang="ko">중중중중중</li>
    </ul>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a very nice solution and works well within the existing `treewalker` solution I had started! Thank you for your help!